# Having issues with html and form facades

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

The problem is that form and html fuctions are returning with ASCI values of the tags.

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'delete']) }}
<a href="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete')}}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  Delete
</a>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The result is:

```
&lt;form method=&quot;POST&quot; action=&quot;http://localhost/firstApp/public/cats/1&quot; accept-charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;&lt;input name=&quot;_method&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;DELETE&quot;&gt;&lt;input name=&quot;_token&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;kRqLd1lCbS9qNkH7DX4cZbctUHzbpqONP4FwsSis&quot;&gt;
<a href="http://localhost/firstApp/public/cats/1/delete">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  Delete
</a>
&lt;/form&gt;
```

I have the same problem with link_to functions too. I don't know maybe there is problem with blade template engine?

Also I want to ask if there is a way to use delete routers with links not forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a problem, blade `{{ }}` escapes the output by default.

If you don't want to escape the output just do `{!!  !!}`

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'delete']) !!}
<a href="{!! url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete') !!}">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  Delete
</a>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```